# How to average numbers from a file and put the result back into a new file using C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, average

I am writing a program that will get 10 numbers from a file named numbers.txt and put them into an array, average them, and write the average back into the file. I've already created and stored the file named numbers.txt. When I run my code it doesn't process and I can't figure out why. I'm very new to coding and learning slowly. Can someone check out this code and help me figure this out?

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i = 0, sum = 0, n = 0,avg = 0;
    FILE *numbers.txt;
    fin = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    while(fscanf(numbers.txt, "%d", &n) != EOF){
        sum += n;
        i++;
        avg = (sum / i);
    }
    printf("The average is %d.\n", avg);
    fclose(numbers.txt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it more readable, without half the lines being blank, and with proper indentation.

Comment: I guess you meant `FILE *fin;`, not `FILE *numbers.txt;` (which has invalid syntax)?

Comment: How are you running this code - it shouldn't even compile (`numbers.txt` is not a valid identifier).  Are you *sure* this is the exact code you are compiling and running?

Answer (score 2):

You call `fscanf` with `numbers.txt` as the first argument (and same for `close`). That's not valid, `numbers.txt` isn't a valid symbol name.

You `open`, assigning to `fin`. Replace `numbers.txt` everywhere except in the string with `fin`. You can't have a `.` inside a variable name. What you have shown won't even compile.

---

You should also be checking the result of `fscanf` for things other than `EOF`. You know when you've reached the end of file, but don't know if you've actually read in a value successfully. It should be 1 on successful input.

---

Depending on the structure of your file, you way want to add a space character to the front of that format string, or make some other changes to it, according to the documentation on `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

"...it doesn't process" isn't a very helpful description - you need to tell us exactly what you're seeing.  If the compiler is complaining, then you need to include the compiler errors in the body of your question.  If the code compiles but isn't running correctly, you need to tell us what you expect to happen and what actually is happening (e.g., "I expect to see this particular output, but I'm not getting any output / I'm getting garbage / I'm getting a value I don't expect", etc. ).

If what you've posted is what you're actually trying to run, then you are likely getting a compiler error over the variable `numbers.txt`.  A `.` is not a valid character for an identifier<sup>1</sup>, so a declaration like `FILE *numbers.txt` is going to be rejected by the compiler.

I took the liberty of modifying your code and annotating it - hopefully this will help:

```
/**
 * While the compiler couldn't care less about how you format your code,
 * it's a good idea to use indentation and whitespace to make your code
 * easier for other people to read.  Exact styles and preferences vary,
 * what matters is that you're consistent.  This is the style I prefer.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i = 0, sum = 0, n = 0,avg = 0;
  /**
   * numbers.txt is not a valid identifier - you can't use that as a variable
   * name.  I'm going to assume you meant to use fin as that's the target of
   * your fopen call.  Note that you can initialize the variable with the
   * result of the function call.  
   */
  FILE *fin = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

  /**
   * It's always a good idea to make sure the fopen call succeeded before
   * trying to use the file pointer.
   */
  if ( !fin ) // or fin == NULL 
  {
    fputs( "Could not open numbers.txt", stderr );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  /**
   * With the *scanf functions, it's better to check to see if you
   * got the expected number of inputs rather than checking for EOF.
   * It's possible for *scanf to return 0 if the first input character
   * doesn't match the format specifier - e.g., if you read an 'a' or a 
   * '.' or something like that.  
   * 
   * In this case we expect 1 integer to be read, so we check that fscanf
   * returns 1.  If it doesn't, *then* we check for EOF or bad input.  We'll
   * create a new variable named items_read to store the return value
   * of fscanf.  
   *
   * For this example, we'll bail out immediately if we see bad input.  
   * There are ways to recover from bad input, but they'll make this 
   * example longer than it needs to be.
   */
  int items_read;
  while( (items_read = fscanf(fin, "%d", &n)) == 1)
  {
    sum += n;
    i++;        

    /**
     * We do not need to compute the average in the body of the loop;
     * that's something that only needs to be done after we've read
     * all the inputs.
     */
  }

  /**
   * Make sure we exited the loop normally by checking that items_read is
   * not 0 and that we don't have a read error on the input stream:
   */
  if ( items_read == 0 || ferror( fin ) )
  {
    fputs( "Badly formed input file or error on input - exiting", stderr );
    fclose( fin );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  /**
   * Otherwise we've read to the end of the file.  
   *
   * It's a good idea to free resources (file pointers, dynamically allocated
   * memory, etc.) as soon as you're done with them, rather than waiting
   * until the end of the program, so we'll close the input file here. 
   */
  fclose(fin); 

  /**
   * *Now* we compute the average.
   */ 
  avg = (sum / i);

  printf("The average is %d.\n", avg);


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Remember that integer division yields an integer result - `1/2` results in `0`, *not* `0.5`.  If you want to compute a floating point average, then `n`, `sum`, and `avg` need to be declared as `double`<sup>2</sup>, and you'll need to use `%lf` as the conversion specifier for the `fscanf` call and `%f` as the conversion specifier for the `printf` call:

```
double sum = 0.0, n = 0.0, avg = 0.0;
...
while( (items_read = fscanf( fin, "%lf", &n )) == 1 )
...
printf( "The average is %f\n", avg );
```

---

1. The only punctuation character that can appear in an identifier (variable name, function name, enumeration constant, etc.) is an underscore - `_`.

   Unless you're really constrained for space, or you specifically do not want that level of precision, use `double` instead of `float`.  Most of the time `float` values are implicitly promoted to `double` anyway.